# otree - change button value on click

Tags: bootstrap-4, otree

I have form field made of bootstrap buttons with this choices:

```
def players_choice_choices(self):
    choices = [('A', 1),('B', 2),('Check', 3)]
    return choices
```

I would like to present the 'A','B','Check' choices and after the user will click on the bootstrap button to present the value (1,2,3).
Is there a way of doing this?

Thank you!

Comment: by 'to present the value' you mean showing at the next page what value corresponds to this button?

Comment: Not on the next page, on the same page. The button are not submot button.

Comment: then just change its text via onclick event  using jquery

Comment: The values are calculated so they different each time. For example in ('A',1) I see only the 1, how can I reach the 'A' from the template?

Comment: pass this array via vars_for_template. then render it directly to javascript using `|json` tag: `var = jarray_for_buttons = {{ your_array |json }};`